# bootstrap class adds by jquery without plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add a class in bootstrap form for validation purpose. It is my form

```
<form id= "regForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<label for="FirstName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" id="FirstName" placeholder="First Name">
<span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

and here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#FirstName").focusin(function(){
var is_name = $("input").val();
if(is_name ==='' && is_name === null){
$('div').addClass('has-error');
$('span').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
}
});
});
```

I want that if name is null or empty it should add bootstrap class **glyphicon-remove** in existing class, exactly in same way i want to do it in further form inputs. can some one please help i dont want to use jquery plugin i want to learn it. I am using bootstrap 3.3.7 cdn.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#FirstName").focusin(function(){
    var is_name = $("input").val();
    if(is_name ==='' || is_name === null){
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.addClass('has-error');
      $this.next('span').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
    }
  });
});
```

You had the conditional operator wrong. This:

```
if(is_name ==='' && is_name === null)
```

Needed to be this:

```
if(is_name ==='' || is_name === null)
```

Becuase 'is_name' can never be both an empty string and null at the same time, they're 2 different things.

Next, where you had this line:

```
$('div').addClass('has-error');
```

You're telling jQuery to add the 'has-error' class to EVERY div on the page.

Instead, you can get a reference to the input you just clicked in using $(this), so now you can add the class to the input itself.

You could just use:

```
$(this).addClass('has-error');
```

But because you need to find the 'span' tag, you still need the reference to the input, so a best practice is to cache it using this line:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Now jQuery has a saved variable for the input which is better for performance.

Finally, use jQuery's 'next' method to find the span tag and add the 'glyphicon-remove' class to it:

```
$this.next('span').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you chris just because of i made my own validation :D